# Debugging in SFOAuthCoordinator and SFAuthenticationManager

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, login

We are developing native iOS app which is using Salesforce SDK v2.3.
I was just tracking down some stuff in debug logs and saw this :

```
2014-11-17 15:46:26:963 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFOAuthCoordinator|SFOAuthCoordinator:webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (navType=5): host=login.salesforce.com : path=/services/oauth2/authorize
2014-11-17 15:46:26:964 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFOAuthCoordinator|SFOAuthCoordinator:webViewDidStartLoad: host=(null) : path=(null)
2014-11-17 15:46:26:964 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator:didStartLoad:
2014-11-17 15:46:28:677 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFOAuthCoordinator|SFOAuthCoordinator:webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (navType=5): host=login.salesforce.com : path=/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp
2014-11-17 15:46:29:021 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator:didFinishLoad:error:
2014-11-17 15:46:29:021 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator:didBeginAuthenticationWithView
2014-11-17 15:46:29:021 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFRootViewManager|SFRootViewManager: Presenting view controller (SFAuthorizingViewController).
2014-11-17 15:46:29:052 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFOAuthCoordinator|SFOAuthCoordinator:webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (navType=5): host=login.salesforce.com : path=/
2014-11-17 15:46:29:052 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFOAuthCoordinator|SFOAuthCoordinator:webViewDidStartLoad: host=login.salesforce.com : path=/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp
2014-11-17 15:46:29:052 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator:didStartLoad:
2014-11-17 15:46:29:317 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFOAuthCoordinator|SFOAuthCoordinator:webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (navType=5): host=(null) : path=(null)
2014-11-17 15:46:29:317 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFOAuthCoordinator|SFOAuthCoordinator:webViewDidStartLoad: host=login.salesforce.com : path=/
2014-11-17 15:46:29:317 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator:didStartLoad:
2014-11-17 15:46:29:319 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator:didFinishLoad:error:
2014-11-17 15:46:29:320 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFOAuthCoordinator|SFOAuthCoordinator:webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (navType=5): host=login.salesforce.com : path=/s.gif
2014-11-17 15:46:29:321 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFOAuthCoordinator|SFOAuthCoordinator:webViewDidStartLoad: host=login.salesforce.com : path=/
2014-11-17 15:46:29:321 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator:didStartLoad:
2014-11-17 15:46:29:324 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFOAuthCoordinator|SFOAuthCoordinator:webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (navType=5): host=login.salesforce.com : path=/login/sessionserver190.html
2014-11-17 15:46:29:324 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFOAuthCoordinator|SFOAuthCoordinator:webViewDidStartLoad: host=login.salesforce.com : path=/
2014-11-17 15:46:29:324 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator:didStartLoad:
2014-11-17 15:46:29:339 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator:didFinishLoad:error:
2014-11-17 15:46:29:340 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFOAuthCoordinator|SFOAuthCoordinator:webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (navType=5): host=www.salesforce.com : path=/login-messages/messages.html
2014-11-17 15:46:29:340 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFOAuthCoordinator|SFOAuthCoordinator:webViewDidStartLoad: host=login.salesforce.com : path=/
2014-11-17 15:46:29:340 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator:didStartLoad:
2014-11-17 15:46:29:370 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator:didFinishLoad:error:
2014-11-17 15:46:32:274 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFOAuthCoordinator|SFOAuthCoordinator:webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (navType=5): host=(null) : path=(null)
2014-11-17 15:46:32:274 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFOAuthCoordinator|SFOAuthCoordinator:webViewDidStartLoad: host=login.salesforce.com : path=/
2014-11-17 15:46:32:274 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator:didStartLoad:
2014-11-17 15:46:32:276 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator:didFinishLoad:error:
2014-11-17 15:46:32:397 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator:didFinishLoad:error:
2014-11-17 15:46:32:398 CustomApp[51706:607] DEBUG|SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator:didFinishLoad:error:
```

and my question is why SFOAuthCoordinator is giving me so much logs. And also these logs also cause  our keyboard to hide  by itself.

What are these ?

- setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp
- s.gif
- login/sessionserver190.html
- login-messages/messages.html

Answer (score 1):

These are debug logs that are printed when various `UIWebviewDelegate` methods are called, namely `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` and `webViewDidStartLoad:`. These log messages are suppressed in a release app and it's generally safe to ignore them, though they certainly can be spammy.

> What are these ?
>
> setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp s.gif
>   login/sessionserver190.html login-messages/messages.html

These are various pages and resources that the OAuth manager fetches as part of the authentication process.

> And also these logs also cause our keyboard to hide by itself.

I think you have a completely unrelated problem there. :)

Comment: Hi Jonathan. Thanks for response. Every time SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator:didFinishLoad:error: is called keyboard is dismissing itself. I thought that it is related to SFAuthenticationManager

Comment: Have you looked into the implementation of that delegate method? Is it forcing the webview to lose focus, which would cause the keyboard to disappear?